# Does IPV6 require layer-2 multicast reception?

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to acquaint myself with IPV6 by implementing it on a small embedded processor board.  I've built up the code to send an ICMPv6 neighbor solicitation message and I am able to cause a Linux box on the same subnet to generate an advertisement as a response. The problem is that I am only able to get this to work if I use a layer-2 broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff).  My impression from what I've read so far is that this (layer-2 broadcast) should not be used in IPV6; rather it should be an IPV6 multicast (33:33:xx:xx:xx:xx) layer 2 address; that is derived from local-link address of the target.

Am I correct to assume that I should NOT use a broadcast address here?  Does IPv6 require layer-2 multicast reception?  I haven't found much Ethernet layer 2 information on this, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1:** 
I've built up a good portion of this code now and have answered some of my questions just through experimentation.  Still, I'd like to see something (like an RFC) that verifies that my data (derived empirically) is correct...
When I issue a neighbor solicit (regardless of whether I use MAC-dest-addr=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff or 33:33:00:00:00:01); I get a response.  The destination address of the response is 33:33:00:00:00:01; so I ONLY get the response if I have multicast reception enabled.  As a result, I am concluding that IPv6 REQUIRES a node to have multicast reception enabled. If anyone reads this and knows otherwise, please post! 
BTW... I'm still assuming that I should NOT use layer 2 broadcast; but I tried it in my experimentation anyway.